# A short proof that every nonidentity element in a free group has infinite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is my proof for the fact that every nonidentity element in a free group has infinite order correct?

Suppose that $F$ is the free group on a nonempty set $X$. We have $F\simeq \prod_{x\in X}^w <x> \simeq \sum_{x\in X}\mathbb Z$, and their torsion subgroups are isomorphic too, but the torsion subgroup of $\sum_{x\in X}\mathbb Z$ is the the trivial subgroup so the proof is complete.

Appendix: after the answer, I realized this proof is only applicable for the abelian case, not for the general case

Comment: If you mean free **abelian** group, then I can believe it. The theorem is true for free group also, but you need a different proof.

Comment: Yes, I’m new to this topic and unknowingly my proof was true only for the abelian case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A free group is not generally isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups; e.g., the free group on two elements is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ (for one, it's not abelian).

Instead, think directly about what it would mean for an element to have finite order.

Comment: Thanks. I did not think directly, and extended this method to the general case in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801683/a-short-proof-that-every-nonidentity-element-in-a-free-group-in-the-category-of